# looking for temperature indicating film similar to Thermoscale but for 50C or 60C minimum temp?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

I am trying to measure a heat distribution across multiple heatsinks inside of a housing. I can't get a thermal camera into the housing to be able to measure a temperature distribuiton. I have a thermocouple setup measuring temperatures at some key points but would like a full temperature distribution if possible.

I came across Fujifilm [Thermoscale](https://www.fujifilm.com/us/en/business/industrial-materials/measurement-film/thermoscale) and it looks like a good way to get a 2D measurement of peak temperatures, but it starts to change color at 90C which is much hotter than my heat plates will (hopefully) ever get. I like that it has a permanent color change so that I can let everything cool down and take my time disassembling my equipment. Has anyone worked with a similar material but with a lower temperature color change? Thanks!

Comment: Contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Liquid crystal thermometer?